# How do I make a property throw an exception on set with a Moq mock?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mocking, moq

I'm working on getting some legacy code under test, and we're using Moq 4 for our isolation. There's a class that has a property with validation in the set {} component. I need it to throw an exception when called for one of my tests, but I can't get it to do it. I've tried the following:

```
fakeNetwork
  .Setup(n => n.IpAddress)
  .Throws(new SystemNotFoundException("1.1.1.1");
```

No exception is thrown.

```
fakeNetwork
  .SetupSet(n => n.IpAddress)
  .Throws(new SystemNotFoundException("1.1.1.1");
```

This usage is obsolete. The replacement is .SetupSet(Action), but I'm not sure how I'd make an action that throws an exception. We treat warnings as errors, so I don't know if this would work anyway, but since I won't be able to use the obsolete version anyway, I have't tried to turn the check off.

Any tips would be very helpful!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Adapted from the [Moq docs](http://code.google.com/p/moq/wiki/QuickStart)

```
mock.SetupSet(foo => foo.Name = "foo").Throws<ArgumentException>();
```

Comment: Ok, now I feel like an idiot. That was exactly it, of course. Thanks!

Comment: Don't feel like an idiot, because this will likely help someone else. I ran into a problem a bit similar to this and it took me ages to figure out. It's the 'little things' that really slow you down!

Comment: The above call will throw on setting a specific value. If you want the call to always throw, use:
`mock.SetupSet(foo => foo.Name = It.IsAny<string>()).Throws<ArgumentException>();`